# div element should scroll down till it gets in contact with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've an div element #1 which stick on top the screen while scrolling. Thats working so far. Now further down on the page there is another element #2 and the element #1 should stop scrolling when it gets in contact with #2. To illustrate the scenario I made a sick picture with my paint skills.

[image]

Do somebody have an idea how to do it?

Comment: overflow: hidden; on div maybe.

Comment: well, it'd better if you add some code too...

Answer (score 0):

```
$el1.offset().top + $el1.outerHeight();
```

this will give you the bottom position of first div. Now When you scroll check if taht bottom position of first div is less than top position of second div. if it is less its ok but if it is greater than you can do whatever you want with first div. You can hide it on make its position absolute.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var bott = $el1.offset().top + $el1.outerHeight();
   if(bott > $el2.offset().top){
   $el1.css('display','none');
   // OR
   $el1.css('position','absolute');
  }
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its not working.I outputed the values bott  and $el2.offset().top while they are overlapped. It's weird, the outcome of #1 is something with 3600 and #2 is around 8000...How can that be, if they are actually overlapped?